# How can I easily review a server installed dependencies for unpatched plugins?

Tags: ruby, docker, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am working on a server migration and upgrade, and I don't code in Ruby at all.

Is there an easy way for me to scan / review the gemfile / installed dependencies to check that latest updated / unpatched dependencies?

The code references to a hundred at least dependencies and I am not sure which are no longer the latest stable version.

Comment: That's not generally what you want to do with a complex codebase. Upgrading gems is not like patching an operating system. Even upgrading a single gem, even to a new stable version, can break the entire codebase. Better be in touch with the person maintaining the code instead.

Comment: Thanks Casper, yeah its a not ideal situation where I am just migrating it, and then I realised that most of the gems are out of date, and it makes standing it up on a clean server somewhat difficult. Im not a Ruby coder, and the old coder has left the company.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `bundle` with the [`outdated`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-outdated.1.html) command and using the `--strict` parameter to make sure it lists only compatible gems:

```
bundle outdated --strict
```

But like I said in my comment above, you usually want to know what you are doing if you plan to upgrade any gem. Any changes to the API or functionality of a gem may break part of or the entire codebase. Make sure you have working backups.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I will give this a try on a local version. Im not re-writing the codebase / upgrading it, just doing an check on how much code repair is needed.